# Replace single quotes (') with double quotes (") except apostrophe

Tags: python, json, regex, replace

I have a dataset with invalid json, see snippet below:

```
{'id': 613, 'name': "new year's eve"}
```

I want to replace all the single quotes except apostrophes like in: new **year's**. So the string above should result in valid json like:

```
{"id": 613, "name": "new year's eve"}
```

I have tried a simple string replace in Python: **string.replace("'", "\"")**, but this also changes the apostrophe resulting in:

```
{"id": 613, "name": "new year"s eve"}
```

Is there a way to fix this with regex, like **replace all ' except when encapsulated by "**?

Comment: I have tried that solution before, it does not work in my case because it results in invalid json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast

s = """{'id': 613, 'name': "new year's eve"}"""
d = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(d)
```

Comment: Be aware not to run this on user's input, this is dangerous as it may allow a user to run arbitrary code on the system.

Comment: @NicolasZ, that's `eval` which is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
'(\w+)'\s*:
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/TN2Z4h/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import json, re

string = """{'id': 613, 'name': "new year's eve"}"""

rx = re.compile(r"""'(\w+)'\s*:""")
string = rx.sub(r'"\1":', string)
d = json.loads(string)
print(d)
```

This yields

```
{'id': 613, 'name': "new year's eve"}
```

Better yet: where does this string come from in the first place?

Comment: `{'id': 613, 'name': "here is the content of my string 'foo': 'bar'"}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't work because it matches the text in between quotes. I only want to change the ' to " except when ' is used in a works like: **year's**.

Comment: @Cid: I know very well that it is not perfect.

Comment: @user3190748: Yes, it does. The printed `d` is alread the parsed dictionary. You could print out the string before if you want to see that is has changed.

Comment: *"Better yet: where does this string come from in the first place?"* this question **should** be answered. You shouldn't have to fix an invalid JSON once received

Comment: @Cid: That'S the point, indeed. OP might not have access to the original data processing pipeline though.

Comment: The json is from a huge dataset I received from a 3rd party and I don't have acces to the processing pipeline.

Comment: I wish I could remember from whence, but the same problem crossed my desk a couple of years ago. It was third-party data over which I had no control. In my case a simple `.replace("'", '"')` sufficed (no embedded quotes in the strings).